# Mongoengine datetime "bug" -- saving server started time instead of current timestamp

Tags: python, pymongo, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I'm setting up my model like so:

```
class user(db.Document):
    created_at = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

I'm expecting that whenever a new user instance is `.save()`, it will have the current timestamp. But as I'm testing on my local machine, all timestamp seems to be the timestamp when server started running.

Does anyone else have this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: take a look at the `tz_aware` option of the database connection classes. The default value is False, which means you get naive dates on your application. Set to True to get timezone aware dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to pass in the method and not call it, like so:

```
db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

The way you do it the function is being evaluated only once when the app starts up and so that time is always the value of created_at.

Comment: Thank you so much! This saved my day!